Show that $f$ is not differentiable but partially differentiable at $(0,0)$

Let be $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, where
$$
f(x,y):=\begin{cases}
x,&x\neq y\\1,&x=y, x\neq 0,y\neq 0\\0,&x=y=0
\end{cases}
$$
Show that $f$ is not differentiable but partially differentiable at $(0,0)$.


My approach:
We immediately see that
\begin{align*}
&\text{if }x\neq 0\implies \frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x-0}=\frac{x-0}{x}=1\implies \lim\limits_{x\to0;x\neq 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x-0}=1\\
&\text{if }y\neq 0\implies\frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{y-0}=\frac{0-0}{y}=0\implies \lim\limits_{y\to0;y\neq0}\frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{y-0}=0.
\end{align*}
So both partials exists at point $(0,0)$. However,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\left|f(t,t)-f(0,0)-A\left({t\choose t}-{0\choose 0}\right)\right|}{\Vert {t\choose t}-{0\choose 0}\Vert_\infty}=\frac{|1-0-a_1t-a_2t|}{|t|}\geq\left|\left|\frac{1}{t}\right|-|a_1+a_2|\right|,
\end{align*}
where $A={a_1\choose a_2}$ is an arbitrary but fixed matrix. Letting $t\to0$ shows that the limit is infinite, so that $f$ can't be differentiable at $(0,0)$.
Is this correct?

What is your definition of differentibilty at a point?

@BobDobbs, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. That said, yes it is, except the (anyway useless) $\geq\left|\frac{1}{t}-|a_1+a_2|\right|$.

@AnneBauval what's wrong with the last inequality? I thought it is the quickest way to show that it tends to infinity.

You don't need it to show that, and it is wrong if $t$ and $a_1+a_2$ are both negative.

Matrix $A$ is not so arbitrary. You can take $a_1=a_2=0$ since you computed partial derivatives. @Philipp

Pardon, $a_1=1.$

@AnneBauval I still don't get your point. I simply applied triangle inequality, i.e. $|x-y|\geq ||x|-|y||$ what is wrong with that? (Maybe you were adressing the missing absolute value bars which I added now?)

@BobDobbs even if you take the partials as matirx $A$ you still see that the limit tends to infinity. So what exaclty is wrong by saying "arbitrary" matrix?

$A$ is the Jacobian matrix. Isn't it? @Philipp

@BobDobbs, yes of course

Note that $f$ is discontinuous at the origin, so it cannot be differentiable.

Your final inequality was not an application of $|x-y|\geq ||x|-|y||$, and was wrong in the case I indicated. Now you corrected it, my main objection to your post remains: this site is not a proof-checker (see my 1st comment above).
